# iCloud Get Record Modified Date - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I am trying to get Record Modified date i am using the following code but when debugging i did not find date in the CKAsset:

```
    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let privateDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase
    let wellKnownID: CKRecordID = CKRecordID(recordName: “1”)
    privateDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(wellKnownID, completionHandler: {
        results, error in
        if error == nil {
            let databaseAsset = self.database!.objectForKey("database") as! CKAsset
            regisrationAccount.iCloudDatabase = databaseAsset.fileURL.path!
            println(databaseAsset.valueForKey("size")?.description) // I get the size but there is no modified date with in the object
            println(databaseAsset.description)
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    })
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPnfn.png

Comment: strange, the only thing available on a CKAsset should be the fileURL. You should get the information from accessing that URL. Why are you using self.database!.objectForKey("database") instead of results.objectForKey("database") Did you set the self.database in code what's not in the sample?

Comment: And you should get the modification date form the CKRecord where the asset is a field of.